# tkinter returning all database columns in one column

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to use tkinter to display information from a MongoDB database. However all of the different db columns are being returned in a single column rather than the correct db column. The column headings are displayed correctly and all of the data is there when I expand the column it is displayed in. Here is the relevant code:

```
    columns = list(df.columns.values)
    tree = ttk.Treeview(window, columns=columns, show='headings')
    for column in columns:
        tree.heading(column, text=column)
    for row in rows:
        tree.insert("", tk.end, values=row)
```

If I change the insert line to this I then get the column headings being displayed recursively in each column but no actual row data:

```
    tree.insert("", tk.END, values=list(row))
```

I have looked and looked but cant work out what I am doing wrong and most examples don't involve getting data from a MongoDB database.

If I change the code to this below and miss out the database connection this works fine:

```
    columns = ('BUSINESS ID', 'BUSINESS NAME', 'ORDERS')
    tree = ttk.Treeview(window, columns=columns, show='headings')
    for column in columns:
        tree.heading(column, text=column)
    rows = []
    for n in range(1, 100):
        rows.append((f'id {n}', f'name {n}', f'orders {n}'))
    for row in rows:
        tree.insert('', tk.END, values=row)
```

Comment: What is `rows`?

Comment: Please create a [mcve], preferably with hard-coded data rather than requiring us to create a database.

Comment: Hi Bryan. I have added a hard coded example which is the closest I can get but this works fine. I have also tried this with a csv and it displays fine too

Comment: Include the output of `print(rows)`

Comment: Please don't include images as its not understandable, include code. It looks like `rows` is a `dict` and hence when you loop through, you are looping through its keys only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `rows` looks like a list of `dict`, therefore you need to insert the values of each row (a `dict` item) using `list(row.values())`:

```py
for row in rows:
    tree.insert("", tk.END, values=list(row.values()))
```

As your code have a dataframe `df`, you can use it as below:

```py
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    tree.insert("", tk.END, values=list(row.values))
```

Comment: This indeed worked!!! Thank you so much, you've no idea how much time I have wasted on this! Thanks again